# Flash Displays Black Screen No Video YouTube Firefox 11

Tags: 10.04, xubuntu, flash

The title says it all, Flash Aid has not helped the situation & Google has not thrown up any recent similarities.

I am running Xubuntu LTS.

about:plugins ~     File: libflashplayer.so Version: Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

```
ii  flashplugin-installer                 11.2.202.228ubuntu0.10.04.1                     Adobe Flash Player plugin installer
ii  libswfdec-0.8-0                       0.8.4-1build1                                   SWF (Macromedia Flash) decoder library
ii  swfdec-mozilla                        0.8.2-1ubuntu2                                  Mozilla plugin for SWF files (Macromedia Flash)
```

SOLVED:  Regular update, seems to have solved itself.  Thanks

Comment: type `about:plugins` in ur browser address bar and paste output

Comment: try putting **s** after http in browser address is this resolving your problem

Comment: try running this cmd and put output to this `dpkg -l | grep flash; dpkg -l | grep gnash; dpkg -l | grep swf`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have installed 2 different flash players, they probably overwrite some files from one another. The sane thing to do is uninstall all 3 and reinstall Adobe Flash again. Workarounds like manually downloading files from the internet can work, but the update system will not be aware of it and can broke it again when there is an update available.

You can do it either from the Software Centre, or using the command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer libswfdec-0.8-0 swfdec-mozilla
```

to remove then and:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

To download and install again the official (Adobe) Flash player.

Comment: OK.  Done, but same black screen with Flash under FF.  Does not bother as Chrome is main browser, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Link Updated**

Download this file http:http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/Adobe-Flash-Player-for-Linux-18853.shtml you are looking for libflashplayer.so . Once you find it in this file, overwrite yours. /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin (thats where it was in my system). I have been fighting this for 3 days. This fixed it.

Comment: Tried that.  I believe file to be over written was bigger size than it's replacement?  May try again, but pretty sure that did not work for me.

Comment: Bart, the link that you give us doesn't work, could you post it again? See you

Comment: It looks like you have installed 2 different flash players, they probably overwrite some files from one another. The sane thing to do is uninstall all 3 and reinstall Adobe Flash again. Workarounds like manually downloading files from the internet can work, but the update system will not be aware of it and can broke it again when there is an update available. You can do it either from the Software Centre, or using the command line: sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer libswfdec-0.8-0 swfdec-mozilla to remove then and: sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer To download and install agai